# LPC1343 and JAVA

Tags: java, lpc

Is there a possibility to give commands using Java programming language on a micro-controller/cpu like LPC1343 or LPC1769.

If yes can you tell what library to use in Java?

The main idea is that i want to build a client application using Java programming language , and that client to send some commands on the LPC1343 micro-controller. I read about the library http://rxtx.qbang.org/, it looks like to be a possible solution. The LPC1343 will be a part of an embed project. I only need to read some information from LPC1343 and to give some commands.

Comment: Please elaborate more on the subject. Also : `Thank you in advance. Best Regards George Sand` are unnecessary at StackOverflow

Comment: It looks like this is a a good solution http://jusb.sourceforge.net/, but I hope that someone else, have much more experience in working with LPC and JAVA and it will share with us.